# Error flutter NotificationDetails too many positional arguments

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm using NotificationDetails to show local notifications in my app:

```
class NotificationApi {
  static final _notifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  static final onNotifications = BehaviorSubject<String?>();

  static Future _notificationDetails() async {
    return NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'channel id',
          'channel name',
          'channel description', //here shows the error
          importance: Importance.max,
        ),
        iOS: IOSNotificationDetails(),
    );
  }

  static Future init({bool initScheduled = false}) async {
    final android = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    final iOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
    final settings = InitializationSettings(android: android, iOS: iOS);

    await _notifications.initialize(
      settings,
      OnSelectNotification: (payload) async {
        onNotifications.add(payload);
      },
    );
  }

  static Future showNotification({
    int id = 0,
    String? title,
    String? body,
    String? payload,
  }) async =>
      _notifications.show(
        id,
        title,
        body,
        await _notificationDetails(),
        payload: payload,
      );
}
```

At the moment to implement the third argument in AndroidNotificationDetails(), it is marked as error:

```
   Too many positional arguments: 2 expected, but 3 found.
   Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named 
   arguments.dartextra_positional_arguments_could_be_named
```

And it shows when i clicked on the () of the method:

[image]

I am guiding myself with this tutorial. This code is displayed at minute 2:05
[YouTube Video](https://youtu.be/bRy5dmts3X8)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Channel description is a named parameter, you need to type `channelDescription:"Your description"`

```dart
 android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'channel id',
          'channel name',
          channelDescription:"Your description",  
          importance: Importance.max,
        ),
```

More about [constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors).